# Magento agreement on one page checkout not showing detail of accepted terms & conditions in placed order

Tags: magento-1.9.1

After enabling Magento terms and conditions on one page checkout it's working fine and I am also able to place an order but, where does it sow in order logs that I have accepted terms and conditions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No record is kept, but the customer should be unable to checkout if the box isn't ticked, so there should not be an issue.

[source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/terms-and-condtions)

Comment: but If you delete agreement html from browser debugger it will also work, this should not I think. there should be check at php side too.